# Timestamp issue in log4j

Tags: java, log4j, timestamp, disk

What is the time actually we see in logs with log4j. Is it the time of the event we write some message ? or is it the time when the message will be written to logs on disk. Considering there is some load on the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is valid for log4j 1.2 only.

The logging contains the time when `logger.log(..)` is called not when the message is written to disk.

For a better understanding please check the source code of log4j. All `logger.log(..)` methods create a new `LogRecord` instance. The constructor of `LogRecord` retrieves the timestamp which is used later to write the timestamp to disk.

Comment: Does that answer your question? In such a case please mark this answer as your favourite answer. Thanks!